# How to upload large file to signed S3 URL from shell using curl

Tags: curl, amazon-s3

I am using *curl* to upload a large file (>5GB) to a signed URL on S3.

curl:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/file.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=EMIRJN3IU7FNIXRK5JKQ%2F20170906%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170906T070720Z&X-Amz-Expires=100&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost&x-amz-acl=public-read&X-Amz-Signature=431a62c997c8202512996244b0267e83cb52c0c9d306376e15f43e22c07938f9' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-zip-compressed' \
  --upload-file '/tmp/file.zip'
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>EntityTooLarge</Code>
    <Message>Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size</Message>
    <ProposedSize>7192576000</ProposedSize>
    <MaxSizeAllowed>5368709120</MaxSizeAllowed>
    <RequestId>61803227A539E1F6</RequestId>
    <HostId>75RCx1xBVCzVeBbof6GZRN0fAY9/tVTDUaavdXXXkNMVWPWLLhkvZx--MxjaalxlWuiuAg6qCA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is due to [AWS S3 forcing multipart upload for files larger than 5GB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html).

How can I perform multipart upload to signed URL on S3 using curl?

If that's not possible, are there other tools. Note that this is a public upload, i.e. AWS CLI is not an option because the user running these uploads does not have our credentials.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html

Comment: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd